# Unicode code to text SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode

I have a problem uinsg SQL Server 2008.

I need to write a query with selection and join of several tables. It's all OK. For about 32000 rows.

But there are some tables with columns (logins and so on) that contain cells with numbers like `0041007600750074006F0076005200590073` or `00420072007500330065006E0073006B006100790062`, but not the text as I want it to be.

It's Unicode coded text. Online converter converts to text.

The question is how can I easily decode these numbers in query so to get the text as a result.

`abcd..` instead of `0041007600750074006F0076005200590073`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use convert to decode the string as for example:

`SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x' + '420072007500330065006E0073006B006100790062', 1))`

Remark: I did remove the first to zero's of your string...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
I've done like this:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x' + SUBSTRING(SUA.[USER_NAME], 3, LEN(SUA.[USER_NAME])), 1)) AS USER_NAME_TEXT
```

It works.